# Jetpack plugin - 'posts_per_page' not overriding 'Blog pages show at most' option, also different values for different post types?

Tags: pagination, plugin-jetpack

I have Jetpack installed and I have got Infinite Scroll working on my theme but `posts_per_page` is having no effect, the number of posts initially shown and loaded is my "Blogs show at most" number in Settings → Reading which is 5.

```
function mytheme_render_infinite_scroll() {
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if ('mytheme_custom_post_type' == get_post_type()) :
                get_template_part( 'content', 'archive-custom' );
            else :
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            endif;
    endwhile;
}

function mytheme_jetpack_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
        'container'      => 'content',
        'footer_widgets' => 'footer-widgets',
        'type'           => 'click',
        'render'         => 'mytheme_render_infinite_scroll',
        'wrapper'        => true,
        'posts_per_page' => '15'
    ) );
}
```

I am also rendering a different content template depending on what the current post type is using the `mytheme_render_infinite_scroll` function above. It would be great if I could set the `posts_per_page` value to be different depending on post type too, eg. have 5 posts per page show on a Blog archive but have 15 posts per page show on an archive page of `mytheme_custom_post_type`. I am not sure how to do this, my attempt would be:

```
function mytheme_render_infinite_scroll() {
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if ('mytheme_custom_post_type' == get_post_type()) :
                get_template_part( 'content', 'archive-custom' );
            else :
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            endif;
    endwhile;
}

function mytheme_infinite_scroll_posts_per_page()
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if ('mytheme_custom_post_type' == get_post_type()) :
            return 15;
        else :
            return 5;
        endif;
endwhile;

function mytheme_jetpack_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
        'container'      => 'content',
        'footer_widgets' => 'footer-widgets',
        'type'           => 'click',
        'render'         => 'mytheme_render_infinite_scroll',
        'wrapper'        => true,
        'posts_per_page' => 'mytheme_infinite_scroll_posts_per_page'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_jetpack_setup' );
```

... but I have no idea if this would work, Jetpack is probably not set up to handle this! Can't test it either because as I said above the `posts_per_page` argument isn't having any effect.

The Jetpack support doc is here: http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/

**EDIT:** I've done some testing and the conclusion I've come to is Jetpack is built so that the `posts_per_page` argument only has an effect if the `type` is not set as `click`. I can't find this specifically stated in any documentation so I may be wrong but I've got `posts_per_page` working with `'type' => 'scroll'` but not with `'type' => 'click'`

Comment: Does it work if you omit the `posts_per_page` argument in the Jetpack setup function?

Comment: Yes, Jetpack Infinite scroll in general is working, whether or not `posts_per_page` is there, but the only thing that seems to affect the number of posts that are loaded is the value entered in Settings > Reading. I can't test my idea for `mytheme_infinite_scroll_posts_per_page` (although I highly doubt it will work) because it depends on the `posts_per_page` argument working. Not sure if I understand the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin author has confirmed on the Wordpress Support Forums that `posts_per_page` only works if the `type` is set to `scroll` and not `click`, see http://wordpress.org/support/topic/posts_per_page-not-having-any-effect?replies=5#post-5058675